# Is there any official document about the date( ) function in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

[PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)
I have read the Postgres manual about the date function for many hours but i can't find any instruction about the use of `date( )` in Postgres.

Consider the following

```
select DATE('2010-01-01 12:00:00');



 date
------------
 2010-01-01
```

Where can i get the official document recording the use of DATE () here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a different way of writing a [type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)

> It is also possible to specify a type cast using a function-like syntax:
> `typename ( expression )`
> However, this only works for types whose names are also valid as function names. For example, `double precision` cannot be used this way, but the equivalent `float8` can

So, `DATE('2010-01-01 12:00:00')` is equivalent to `'2010-01-01 12:00:00'::date` or `cast('2010-01-01 12:00:00' as date)`